# How to get custom XML from T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have this query:

```
select f.n, t.l, grp.n, cat.n, col.n, col_value
        from fc 
            inner join f on f.idfc = fc.idfc
            inner join t on t.idf = f.idf
            inner join grp on grp.idt = t.idt
            inner join cat on cat.idgrp = grp.idgrp
            inner join col on col.idcat = cat.idcat
            inner join col_value on col_value.idcol = col.idcol
    for xml auto, root('fc')
    ;
```

It returns this xml:

```
<fc>
  <f n="341.11.7">
    <t l="A">
      <grp n="ID">
        <cat n="10">
          <col n="R">
            <col_value col_value="341" />
          </col>
          <col n="S">
            <col_value col_value="11" />
          </col>
          <col n="H">
            <col_value col_value="7" />
          </col>
        </cat>
      </grp>
    </t>
  </f>
</fc>
```

But I need that col_value elements must be like following:

```
<col_value>341</col_value>
```

So, how can I modify the query to reach the following result?

```
<fc>
  <f n="341.11.7">
    <t l="A">
      <grp n="ID">
        <cat n="10">
          <col n="R">
            <col_value>341</col_value>
          </col>
          <col n="S">
            <col_value>11</col_value>
          </col>
          <col n="H">
            <col_value>7</col_value>
          </col>
        </cat>
      </grp>
    </t>
  </f>
</fc>
```

Thanks everybody.
Charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    f.n, t.l, grp.n, cat.n, col.n,
    (select col_value for xml path(''), type)
from fc 
    inner join f on f.idfc = fc.idfc
    inner join t on t.idf = f.idf
    inner join grp on grp.idt = t.idt
    inner join cat on cat.idgrp = grp.idgrp
    inner join col on col.idcat = cat.idcat
    inner join col_value on col_value.idcol = col.idcol
for xml auto, root('fc')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/550e1/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

try change your query like this:

```
select f.n, t.l, grp.n, cat.n, col.n, (select col_value for xml path,type).query('/row/col_value') )
    from fc 
        inner join f on f.idfc = fc.idfc
        inner join t on t.idf = f.idf
        inner join grp on grp.idt = t.idt
        inner join cat on cat.idgrp = grp.idgrp
        inner join col on col.idcat = cat.idcat
        inner join col_value on col_value.idcol = col.idcol
for xml auto, root('fc')
;
```

I hope this helps.